# Syncing up a specific schema between two RDS Tables (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Currently we have two dbs in AWS RDS (Postgres). One for Demo (Internal Testing) and another for beta environment. Both dbs have a schema called "strapi" which contains common data to display to user. Our use case is that whenever the admin updates the strapi data in demo db, it should reflect in beta as well. So I was searching for AWS services that supports our use case.

Searched for similar questions and I found people recommending AWS DMS. So went ahead and created endpoints and ran a full load task with "Truncate" option for Target Preparation Mode.

The task failed with following error

```
"RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 0A000 NativeError: 1 Message: ERROR: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint; Error while executing the query [1022502]  (ar_odbc_stmt.c:4828). Failed to truncate table strapi.programs [1022502]  (odbc_endpoint_imp.c:4372)"
```

Tried setting session_replication_role parameter to replica on target database in RDS and still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I still am not sure whether AWS DMS is a good service for our use case.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it not possible to just run your database migrations in both environments?

Comment: Just run your migrations in both environments, preferably before you deploy your application code, within your pipeline - you're using DMS for something it's not intended for

Comment: Hey @jordanm, let me quickly clarify my question. I need to create a pipeline (not necessarily automatic) such that any changes in a particular schema in demo db needs to be reflected in beta db.

Comment: Hey @ErmiyaEskandary, let me quickly clarify my question. I need to create a pipeline (not necessarily automatic) such that any changes in a particular schema in demo db needs to be reflected in beta db. Also if DMS is not the right service, please suggest me the right service.

Comment: RDS replication between 2 instances using DMS where 1 of them is not a read replica is only possible for Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure whether AWS DMS is the correct service for my use case of creating a pipeline such that any changes in a particular schema in demo db should be reflected in beta db. But found the solution for the above DMS Task error.

```
"RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 0A000 NativeError: 1 Message: ERROR: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint; Error while executing the query [1022502]  (ar_odbc_stmt.c:4828). Failed to truncate table strapi.programs [1022502]  (odbc_endpoint_imp.c:4372)"
```

One can manually drop the foreign key constraints and once the full load migration task is completed, we can recreate the foreign key constraints

A simple script to drop foreign key constraints (Taken from https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/97047)

```
create table if not exists dropped_foreign_keys (
        seq bigserial primary key,
        sql text
);

do $$ declare t record;
begin
    for t in select conrelid::regclass::varchar table_name, conname constraint_name,
            pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true) constraint_definition
            from pg_catalog.pg_constraint r
            where r.contype = 'f'
            -- uncomment the below line for current schema only:
            -- and r.connamespace = (select n.oid from pg_namespace n where n.nspname = current_schema())
        loop

        insert into dropped_foreign_keys (sql) values (
            format('alter table %s add constraint %s %s',t.table_name, t.constraint_name, t.constraint_definition));

        execute format('alter table %s drop constraint %s', t.table_name, t.constraint_name);

    end loop;

    
end $$;
```

And to recreate the dropped foreign key constraints

```
do $$ declare t record;
begin
    -- order by seq for easier troubleshooting when data does not satisfy FKs
    for t in select * from dropped_foreign_keys order by seq loop
        execute t.sql;
        delete from dropped_foreign_keys where seq = t.seq;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Also note that for the full load task, there will not be any problem with migration as long as the constraints are created after the migration is completed on the target instance. But if you expect any updates on target instance for the tables in questions while the migration is running then you may see some issues with inconsistency because of dropping foreign key constraints.